# Python treat variable as literal/raw string

Tags: python, string, literals

I can't believe it's that difficult to treat a **variable** as a **raw string**! I have searched and found questions alike, but no proper answer.

I have a variable with domain name stored in. e.g. 'domain\user', I need to get the username only using `re`. The problem is Python gives me hex values for special character combinations, for example when I have `\b` in the string.

I just need to get the literal string from the variable, and nothing else.

```
author = list[0] // list[0] contains 'domain\blah'
author = re.sub('.*\\\\(.+)$', r'\1', author)
```

I'd expect `blah`, getting `'domain\x08lah'`!

Saving the string as raw string at the start is not an option, because I'm getting the string from other regex operations.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I was mistaken by assuming the variable had a single slash in. In fact, when getting the variable from another operation, the backclash had already been escaped. So I was making it a problem for myself when trying to create a test scenario.

Comment: How was `list[0]` set in the first place? You defined a regular string somewhere and didn't escape the backslash there.

Answer (score 3):

A raw string literal is only used to *create* string values, by avoiding (most) string escape codes that a regular string literal would use.

Your string *started* with the `\x08` character; it never contained a backslash and a `b` character. If you defined the value contained in `list[0]` with a string literal, you forgot to escape the backslash. If the data came from somewhere else, you are looking at a raw hex byte value of 08:

```
>>> list_0 = 'domain\x08lah'
>>> list_0[6]
'\x08'
>>> len(list_0[6])
1
>>> ord(list_0[6])
8
```

If this byte was meant to be two characters instead, you could repair the data with string replacement:

```
>>> list_0.replace('\b', '\\b')
'domain\\blah'
```