# Replace single backslash into double backslash with Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace `\` into `\\` with python from pattern matching.
For example, `$$\a\b\c$$` should be matched replaced with `$$\\a\\b\\c$$`.

I couldn't use the regular expression to find a match.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile("\$\$([^$]+)\$\$")
>>> a = "$$\a\b\c$$"
>>> m = p.search(a)
>>> m.group(1)
'\x07\x08\\c'
```

I can't simply make the input as raw string such as `a=r'$$\a\b\c$$'` because it's automatically processed with markdown processor. 
I also found that I couldn't use replace method:

```
>>> a.replace('\\','\\\\')
'$$\x07\x08\\\\c$$'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have access to `a`'s initialization? If you do, try `a=r'$$\a\b\c$$'` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l )

Comment: @BorrajaX: No, it's a return value from the regular expression.

Comment: Hmmmmpffrrr... Daang... Could you post the part that calculates that `a`? Once your string is evaluated, there's no way back (it doesn't know that `\x07` came from `\a`. Maybe something can be done before you get that `a`?

Comment: I found this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18055356/289011 ) by the almighty Martijn Pieters. You're not gonna love it, though... but if he says so, that's probably right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having trouble is because the string you're inputting is `$$\a\b\c$$`, which python translates to `'$$\x07\x08\\c$$'`, and the only back slash in the string is actually in the segment '\c' the best way to deal with this would be to input a as such

```
a=r'$$\a\b\c$$'
```

This will tell python to convert the string literals as raw chars. If you're reading in from a file, this is done automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string with single backslashes, then join the resulting list with double backslashes.

```
s = r'$$\a\b\c$$'
t = r'\\'.join(s.split('\\'))
print('%s -> %s' % (s, t))
```